# MongoDB to BigQuery DataFlow job does not transfers all the data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to transfer some data from MongoDB to BigQuery through Pubsub. I have a Python Script that reads the data from MongoDB and publishes the messages to a Pubsub topic. I am using the default subscription.
Then a Dataflow job takes those messages and writes them to BigQuery. I created the DataFlow job from template (Mongo to BQ CDC).
The DataFlow is working fine. I do not get any errors. But it does not transfer all the data. It transfers only a portion of the data randomly. And when I run the Python script again a different portion of the data get transferred. Any pointers why this might be happening?

Comment: This is hard to debug without the details. I suggest you open a support ticket with GCP.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.